# Fazendo operações dentro do Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

Estou tentando fazer a seguinte coisa com este código

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
# Criando uma série no pandas que represente a indexação das linhas como valores temporais 
# Por exemplo, datas do calendário do ano.
dates = pd.date_range('2019-09-21', '2019-09-25')
dates 
#Criando um dataframe de uma linha e uma coluna, ou uma série. 
#renomeando as linhas ou índices i da série ou matriz ou dataframe (df) através do comando 'index' 
# Acrescentando a série de datas a Série numérica criada. 
#E Agora vamos inserir variáveis reais ao problema
#inserindo a variável Montante inicial como uma série numérica
MontanteInicial= Series([6986.16, 6986.16, 6986.16, 6986.16, 6986.16], index = dates)
MontanteInicial
#Repetindo o processo para os valores ganhos diariamente em relação ao dia anterior. 
#Podemos construir uma tabela de valores que apresente o lucro diário em relação ao dia anterior
MontanteFinal = Series([6990, 6991, 6994, 6998, 7000], index = dates)
MontanteFinal #
Operação de subtração entre as componentes da lista - Criando através da operação, uma lista que me diz quanto lucrei no total. 
#Calculando a diferença entre os índices da matriz/Dataframe e plotando a resposta no próprio DF.
LucroTotal = MontanteFinal-MontanteInicial
LucroTotal
TaxaSelic = Series(['5.5%', '5.5%', '5.5%', '5.5%', '5.5%'], index = dates)
#Criando um DataFrame que usa como colunas, duas séries que representam numeros aleatórios associado a duas possiveis variáveis.
df_temp = DataFrame({'Montante Final': MontanteFinal, 'Montante Inicial': MontanteInicial, 'Taxa Selic': TaxaSelic, 'Lucro Total' : LucroTotal})
df_temp'''
```

O código está importando a seguinte tabela [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria saber se ao invés de usar o comando dates=pd.date_range em data pré-especificadas, se é possível introduzir um While no meio e fazer com que ele ficasse acrescentando os valores da data atual, pensei em tentar usar o comando date.today() mas ainda não pensei muito sobre como fazer isso.. Porém, a ideia era usar esse comando para anexar mais uma coluna a este DF, em que eu pegasse a diferença entre os Lucros Totais e descontasse sempre em relação ao dia anterior. 
Por exemplo, Lucro Diário [0] = 3.84 pois foi o primeiro valor da tabela
Lucro diário [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Mbb.png) = 1.00 (4.84 - 3.84) e assim por diante..

Minha dúvida no caso é, como eu poderia operar o While de forma que ele reconhecesse os valores do DataFrame como índices da matriz e eu conseguisse operar entre eles até uma Data Específica?

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi você quer fazer alguma operação entre as colunas somente se a data estiver em um intervalo específico, é isso?

Comment: exatamente isso, desculpe a demora pela resposta